# Why does my heat pump's fan always stay on when in heat mode?

Tags: wiring, heating, thermostat

I have a heat pump. This unit does have emergency heat. I only know this because I have used it. I noticed that the other day the fan stays on with the heat on. The fan switch set to auto and the temp set way below the actual room temperature. I removed my thermostat to examine the wiring and it has E and W2 connected together. Could this be the reason for the fan constantly running?

Comment: Sorry I meant to include that I thought (Based on a manual from a previous thermostat that I installed) that E and W2 are only supposed to be connected if there was no actual emergency heat.

Comment: Use the edit button to add new information so it's readily apparent to readers.

Answer (score 1):

The heating fan will run for a cool down after the heating elements are turned off. If you listed your Furnace Model and your thermostat model we could check the wiring for you and suggest what you need to do.

But yes it sounds like the Thermostat is wired incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. I will gt that for you when I get back home. at work now.